# Cannot load message class for [roboclaw/RoboclawEncoderSteps]

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get joy teleop working with a Roboclaw motor controller.

I'm using this node to interface with the controller.

https://github.com/csvance/roboclaw

Current setup:

ROS Melodic
Jetson Nano
Roboclaw 2x15 Motor controller

While troubleshooting I'm unable to rostopic echo /motor_enc. I'm getting the following error.

```
rostopic echo /motor_enc
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [roboclaw/RoboclawEncoderSteps]. Are your messages built?
```

catkin_make compiled the project successfully with no errors.

I'm using AMT10 quadrature encoders and I'm able to see the counters increase or decrease with BasicMicroMotionStudio software. I've tried lowing the encoders PPS settings to the lowest available resolution. Current resolution settings are at 48 pulses a second which gives me around 482 steps per meter.

Has anyone encountered this issue before? I'm a beginner with ROS and I'm not sure where to start looking. I would really appreciate anyone's assistance with this issue.

This is the launch file i'm using.

```
<!--
    Roboclaw 0x80 Index: 0
-->
<node pkg="roboclaw" type="roboclaw_node" name="roboclaw" output="screen">
    <param name="~serial_port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
    <param name="~baudrate" value="115200"/>
    <param name="~roboclaws" value="1"/>
</node>


<node pkg="roboclaw" type="diffdrive_node" name="diffdrive" output="screen">
    <param name="~roboclaws" value="1"/>
    <param name="~steps_per_meter" value="482.88"/>
    <param name="~base_width" value="0.31"/>      
<param name="~swap_motors" value="false"/>
    <param name="~invert_motor_1" value="false"/>
    <param name="~invert_motor_2" value="false"/>
    <param name="~var_pos_x" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="~var_pos_y" value="0.01"/>
    <param name="~var_theta_z" value="0.01"/>
<node pkg="teleop_twist_joy" type="teleop_node" name="joystick_to_twist">   
     
</node>
```

video of issue:

https://youtu.be/B7CpNJxM1HM

Terminal Output - I can't attach txt documents

ROSTOPICS

```
/cmd_vel
/diagnostics
/joy
/joy/set_feedback
/motor_cmd_vel
/motor_enc
/odom
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf

ivan@WiRover:~/Downloads/maestro-linux$ echo /motor_cmd_vel
/motor_cmd_vel
ivan@WiRover:~/Downloads/maestro-linux$ rostopic echo /motor_cmd_vel
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [roboclaw/RoboclawMotorVelocity]. Are your messages built?
ivan@WiRover:~/Downloads/maestro-linux$ rostopic echo /motor_cmd_vel
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [roboclaw/RoboclawMotorVelocity]. Are your messages built?
ivan@WiRover:~/Downloads/maestro-linux$ rostopic echo /motor_enc
ERROR: Cannot load message class for [roboclaw/RoboclawEncoderSteps]. Are your messages built?
```

/cmd_vel OUTPUT

```
---
linear: 
  x: 0.00429909443483
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.155911833048
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.159702554345
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.177258729935
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.199649676681
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.225381597877
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.25251096487
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular: 
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
---
linear: 
  x: 0.278499871492
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
```

/odom OUTPUT

```
header: 
  seq: 3086
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 237917080
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3087
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 338498865
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3088
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 438024746
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3089
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 538186524
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3090
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 638743309
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3091
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 739987868
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3092
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 840263762
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3093
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007758
    nsecs: 938392377
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3094
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007759
    nsecs:  38304879
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3095
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007759
    nsecs: 138105817
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3096
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007759
    nsecs: 238127853
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
header: 
  seq: 3097
  stamp: 
    secs: 1583007759
    nsecs: 340652697
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -19.4368515607
      y: -17.7955061665
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.702041753232
      w: 0.71213578531
  covariance: [0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
---
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345650/cannot-load-message-class-for-%5Broboclaw/roboclawencodersteps%5D/) by [hellraiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/52195/hellraiser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found problem to issue.

Increased encoder resolution to 2048 pulses per second. re-tuned for position and velocity with BasicMicroMotionStudio. Changed "steps_per_meter" parameter to account for new PPS settings.

Original error message was solved by sourcing devel/setup.bash.

---

Originally posted by [hellraiser](https://answers.ros.org/users/52195/hellraiser/) with karma: 16 on 2020-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0